# How do I tell awk I want the second to last and third to last tokens from a tab-delimited line?

Tags: awk

I'm using a bash script.  I have a tab delimited file with data that looks like

```
Afghanistan     AF      AFG     004
ALA     Aland Islands   AX      ALA     248
Albania AL      ALB     008
Algeria DZ      DZA     012
```

I want to rewrite the data like so

```
AF=AFG
AX=ALA
AL=ALB
DZ=DZA
```

which boils down to extracting the third to last token, writing an equals, and then printing the second to last token.  I thought "awk" could help me, but I don't know how to say "second to last".  This doesn't cut it

```
awk '{print $2=$3}' /tmp/country_data.tsv
```

How can I extract the data in the way I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk '{printf "%s=%s\n", $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' file`